# How do I update only a specific svn external on first update?

Tags: svn

I've successfully added the external repository and we're able to update the repo by doing a recursive update on the parent folder, and the external appears correctly.

```
svn up parent
```

However, there is development work in the parent folder that doesn't need to go up to staging/production. I'm having difficulty targeting the external only without doing a recursive update on the whole directory. It gives me a miss every time when I use

```
svn up -r 6 parent/external/
```

I appreciate any advice on making the initial update of a single external without updating the whole directory.

As a side note: the company I'm working with uses trunk with file version numbers for deployments (not ideal).

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: No error message, only "Updated to Revision 6"

Comment: So what do you mean by "it gives me a miss"? You are trying to update it to revision 6, it's already updated to r6, so it does nothing. Please explain what you think is wrong.

Comment: I meant "please explain why you think anything is wrong".

Comment: Nothing is technically 'wrong' as in an error. I simply can't do an initial update on a single external without doing an update on the entire parent directory. The external doesn't live in the parent directory yet, though it is set in svn:externals.

Comment: If I do a recursive update on the parent directory, it pulls in the external just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my understanding of what you've written in the comments what you are seeing is normal behavior: until the external is actually checked out you can't update it since it's not under version control, yet. `svn:external` property is just a directive to SVN client to check out something from another repository. Once it's done you can updated and commit it separately from the rest. There are even a command switch -  `--ignore-externals` - that makes it easier.

Comment: Thanks for the input. That makes sense. I was hoping for a workaround, but the real error is how the client's workflow is setup. Everything is sourced from trunk, so we have this awful concoction of stable/experimental code in trunk which makes recursive updates almost impossible.